# Socket hangs up in accessing kubernetes resources

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, localhost, nginx-ingress

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm practicing a project which used to create some kubernetes resources and I used windows Docker desktop and access kubernetes inside of it.
Here are some resources i create with Kubernetes.

- Auth Deployment & ClusterIP (Nodejs project API)
- Client Deployment & ClusterIP (React project frontend)
- Ingress service for routing.

I automate these resources with skaffold.

This is code for auth deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: auth-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: auth
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: dani100/auth
          env: 
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef: 
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: auth-srv
spec: 
  selector: 
    app: auth
  ports: 
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3005
      targetPort: 3005
```

This is the code for client deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: dani100/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

and here is the code for ingress service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3005
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

As you can see i put **localhost** inside of ingress configuration instead of some different url, because I'm practicing on a company given laptop, so I don't have admin access to specify some other url. As stated with **localhost**, it was working nice but somehow it stopped working suddenly.

For the resources,

- All deployments are **available** and **ready**.
- All pods are **ready** and status is **running**.
- All services are there **available**.

But the problem is I can't access these resources now. I used to access **Auth resources** in Postman with this get request (https://localhost/api/users/currentuser). It ended up in error "Error: socket hang up". But when i tried on chrome it returns "ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR". It's same error on chrome when i access the client resource.

Regarding "socket hang up" issue, I researched about it so there is a solution of adding extra header (Content-Length => application/vnd.api+json). But this didn't resolve the issue and I'm having another issue.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx</center>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know what is the problem, Why it is blocks or hangs up the requests.

Kindly give me a solution for this issue because I'm stuck in middle of the project.

Is specifying a host will solve the issue of accessing the resources?

Is there any hidden firewall which blocks the requests to access the kubernetes resources?

Kindly give an idea OR solution to resolve this issue. Your ideas or solutions will be highly appreciated. Is there any other thing that I missed or you might need to view, I will provide it.

Thanks